# using experimental_relax_shapes=True for Model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a NN and training via Model.fit() takes quite long. I allways get the following:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 12 calls to <function Model.make_train_function.<locals>.train_function at 0x7f128aee0ae8> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

Is there a way to tell Model.fit() to use experimental_relax_shapes=True ?

In other words, I'd like to write

```
@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
```

before the definition of Model.fit(). How can I do this?

If I do something like this:

```
@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
def fit(x):
  return model.fit(x)
```

I get

```
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.fit` inside a `tf.function`. `Model.fit is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`. Please move the call to `Model.fit` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s. Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like: `model(x)`.
```

So I actually want to change the tf.function managed by Model.fit to use experimental_relax_shapes=True .

Comment: Does this [article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/) helped?

Comment: Does it https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35303#issuecomment-569057679 helps ?

Comment: While instructive, those didn't help. My model is fast at predicting, because I use experimental_relax_shapes=True before every self-difined call function. Yet model.fit() seems to not use this, so training takes quite long. I'm also already using a batch size of 1.

Comment: EDIT: Added something that didn't work to clarify what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by writing my own training loop like the first example here:
https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

The curious thing was that when I put @tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True) before the definition of the function that runs the loop, the training steps took around 30 to 40 seconds. When I tried it without, they took less than a second.

Comment: That is curious. After writing your own training loop, you decided to leave `experimental_relax_shapes=True` off?